# SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, web-services, axis

I use axis to hit webservice, I offer Object[] params, occasionally exception happens as follows:

> *AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>       at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
>       at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
>       at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)*

The exception seems like that the xml it uses is with BOM or some wrong character,but I only offer Object[] params,not a xml.And the exception only occurs now and then.
 Quick help would be appreciated,thanks.
The following is my code:

```
**public java.lang.String fireRule(java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1, java.lang.String arg2,
        java.lang.String arg3, boolean arg4) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
    _call.setOperation(_operations[0]);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
    _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://service.databus.brms.sinosoft.com/", "fireRule"));
    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
    Log.debug(RuleServiceImplServiceSoapBindingStub.class,
            " begin::::_call.invoke" + arg0 + ", " + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + ", " + arg3 + ", " + arg4);
    try {
        java.lang.Object _resp = _call
                .invoke(new java.lang.Object[] { arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, new java.lang.Boolean(arg4) });**
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` I only offer Object[] params,not a xml`? 
Can you provide the bit of code doing the parsing and an example of your input which produces the Exception

Comment: The code can be seen in the image

Comment: Please don't use images, paste your code in your question

Comment: Can you give examples of the values passes in arg0, ..., arg4 ?

Comment: ebao
uw
NP
123456789
false